# Redirect user after return false

Tags: php

I have some validation fields like this :

```
if (empty($_POST['finalidade_imob']) || $finalidade_imob == "Escolha 1" || 
        !in_array($_POST['finalidade_imob'], $fi_options)) {    
    $finalidade_imob = "Escolha 1";
    $error++;
} else {
    $finalidade_imob = $_POST['finalidade_imob'];
}

//on the end
if ($error !== 0) {
    return false;
}
```

But the location of my form is on bottom of my page, so when `return false` is called the page is reloaded on the top.

If i put this:

```
if ($error !== 0) {
    header('location:perfil.php#content_cadastro_completo');    
    return false;
}
```

This page is reloaded for exactly to the place i need, but `return false` dont work... I know why `return` dont work, i put that for explain what i need...

So what i need do to goal this target?

Sorry my bad english...

**Edit** Without js... Only PHP.

Comment: you'll need to use JS for this. PHP/header won't go to a placeholder. - *"Without js... Only PHP."* - No can do.

Comment: Tks for atention... If js disable in browser i dont have another way to this goal ? Can do other function not only header...

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news here, but no.

Comment: Dont need apologize man, i trhusty you, but the way not exist until  find the one...

Comment: you may work around this by add a condition layer , for example , `if ($error1){ return false;} else if ($error2){ header....}`

Comment: @Fred-ii- " PHP/header won't go to a placeholder" i dont think is true has i say "header('location:perfil.php#content_cadastro_completo'); " work fo me

Comment: @MagicHat fair enough.

Comment: its fine, np.....

Comment: *"but return false dont work"* - You want `true` then, try that. Or just use `exit;` instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- tks, i gona think something with this to work

Comment: Hey man, i find one solution, i put `placeholder` in my `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>#content_cadastro_completo"`you see some problem in this solution, i know this solution maybe off topic my question but in general u see problems ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ forget call you

Comment: if it works, go for it ;-) seems ok to me

Comment: @Fred-ii- nice tks for atention... need close that question ?

Comment: welcome. Stack lets you submit your own answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question no clear for this solution, but in my all context this work.

The solution that I found is put placeholder in my `action`.

`action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>#content_cadastro_c‌​ompleto"`

and

```
if($error !== 0)
{   return false;//no need header() to go to the placeholder...
}
```